# How to center a <h2>?

Tags: html, css

I have an `h2` header text with the class name "headertekst". I want to center it. I tried to use `margin-left: auto`, `margin-right: auto` and `width: 100%` but nothing happened.

I can give it a `margin-left: 20%` which will center it but that's just on my laptop. It will not be centered on other screen sizes and on mobile devices.

How do I center it the correct way?

Answer (score 33):

You can just add style in h2 as:

```
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Text</h2>
```

Answer (score 22):

```css
h2.headertekst {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="headertekst">Test 1</h2>
```

Comment: I would rather use the class he mentioned, because he wants to differ this specific <h2> element from other possible headers.

Comment: Just add the class and use it that's it.

Comment: That's right @avilac. The OP is asking for a way to center the element. What selector they'll use is case-specific.

Comment: At least add it to your answer... Because that's what he's looking for, although your answer is certanly correct.

Comment: @avilac Here we just guide anyone or anyone guide us that how we can solve any issue or what we are doing wrong in our code. And if anyone is asking a question over here he knows how to handle these minor things. Don't you think!

Comment: @aavrug I don't know, i've been here for short time. My idea is to be the most explicit I can with the answer, but you might be right.

Comment: I think the more specific answers are the better, specific questions needs specific answers, also this fixes his case but it will affect all `h2` tags in his page as well, which isn't preferable I guess.

Comment: Because i have a div inside a <h2>, only the first part of the <h2> gets centered. How can i center the whole <h2>? I added text-align: center to my class. U can see the result on interlaser.webovo.nl.

Comment: @avvrug Terrific! :D

Comment: @aavrug : Thank you :)

Comment: @RickvanBaalen Seems you are looking for something else because you have added ```opacity:0;``` to your span tag and also ```position:absolute;```. Now what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Now if you want to center the entire text just remove the ```opacity``` and ```position``` absolute and see the result.

Comment: @aavrug i deleted the opacity:0 and position: absolute but now the animation isn't working correctly anymore. I need al the rotating words on the same position. (only 'professioneel' is on the correct position)

Comment: @RickvanBaalen Could you please provide an working example or something from where we can understand what exactly you want to do.

Comment: @aavrug haha sorry, yes i can. This is what i want to achieve: https://s27.postimg.org/adxgrnaoj/h2_centered.png. When i use text-align center on my <h2> class, this happens: https://i.imgsafe.org/b73919cdc1.png.

Comment: Ok so after doing text align center just add display none to the span which you don't want to display. Because you were using opacity the text was hidden but it was taking the space.

Answer (score 5):

You can use below css for this

```
h2 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**Or**

```
header {
    text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is all you need:

```
.headertekst {
   text-align: center;
}
```

And if you need to center the `h2` itself, then just add the `text-align: center` rule to the parent of the `h2` tag.

Answer (score 3):

```
<h2 class="headertekst"> centered text </h2>

   .headertekst {
    {
      text-align: center;
      width:100%
    }
```

Comment: use `width:100%` also, because there is no width the `text-align:center` property not work , or other one set `text-align:center` to the parent div

Comment: @Nalia: h2 is an block element, therefore do not need `width:100%`

Comment: @AndyTschiersch Do i need to change the <h2> into a <div>? i just want to center the whole sentence, not just the first part of the sentence.

Comment: In that case you should wrap all the elements you want to center inside a div that contains a class with the text-align: center property setted.

Comment: @avilac i made a div containing the <h2> and the other div, but it doesn't always stay centered. I want the header to be just like the one on https://www.webovo.nl. When the length of the variable word changes, the whole sentence jumps to a centered position. that's what i am looking for.

Comment: this works when the h2 is embedded within another class

Answer (score 1):

add style as:

```
.headertekst{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is a workign snippet:

```css
.headertekst{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="headertekst">Align this to center</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem is that the last part of your heading is rotating and position absolute. You have to define an approximate average width of the three rotating words.

```css
body {
  background: #363636;
}
.headertekst {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
.headertekstrotate {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 8px;
  width: 150px;
}
.headertekstrotate span {
  animation: clock 12s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: clock 12s linear infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: clock 12s linear infinite 0s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.headertekstrotate span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
}
.headertekstrotate span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
}
@keyframes clock {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 class="headertekst">Interlaser is
    <div class="headertekstrotate">&nbsp;
      <span>professioneel.</span>
      <span>voordelig.</span>
      <span>betrouwbaar.</span>
    </div>
</h2>
```

---

Other way:

```css
body {
  background: #363636;
}
.headertekst {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
.headertekstrotate {
  position: relative;
}
.headertekstrotate span {
  animation: clock 12s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: clock 12s linear infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: clock 12s linear infinite 0s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
.headertekstrotate span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
}
.headertekstrotate span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 8s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
}
@keyframes clock {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 class="headertekst">&nbsp;
    <div class="headertekstrotate">
      <span>Interlaser is short.</span>
      <span>Interlaser is very very long.</span>
      <span>Interlaser is professioneel.</span>     
    </div>
</h2>
```

Comment: nice, thanks. Ideally i want the text to be centered at all times, like i have on my other website webovo.nl (the 'Wij zijn ...' part). Then it doesn't matter if u use a long word or a short word, it will always jump to a centered position. Do u know how to do that? i added your css and html to  my website (interlaser.webovo.nl)

Comment: Maybe the other way in my answer?

Comment: Nice! your other way is the closest i've been yet. Ideally i want the first two words to be excluded from the animation and just to be static. Only the last word has to rotate between the spans. Do u know how to make that happen and style it so that it looks like a horizontal sentence? Like this: https://s27.postimg.org/adxgrnaoj/h2_centered.png . Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like this.

```css
.headertekst{
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="headertekst">This is Heading</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 .headertekst
    {
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    }
```

```css
.headertekst
{
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  }
```

```html
<h2 class="headertekst">This is center text</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

why use CSS when we have `center` tag i would rather say use center its a old method but it is good
if you want you can use CSS

`<center><h2 class="headertekst">This is Heading</h2></center>`

Answer (score -1):

Simply change the Css properties to this:

```
.headertekst {
width: 100%
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
}
```

Reason: Sometimes `text-align` does not works if there is no width set. And `overflow` should always be kept hidden in these cases. `display: inline-block` As its name says: it displays the element in a line in a block. And finally, `text-align: center` it aligns the text to center.